# How to make drop down (mouseover) list (made with D3) stay longer?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover, dropdown

I have a drop down list when mouse hovers over a histogram made by d3. It disappears as soon as the mouse cursor leaves the histogram. I would like to make the list stay longer so that a visitor can highlight an item on the list or I can add a link to each item that a visitor can click on.

What's an optimal way to achieve this? (delay the disappearance? add padding / margin?)  And, will the list stay on as long as the mouse cursor is on it?

Live demo: http://jbk1109.github.io/tennisMapWithPlayersListOnHover.html

Thank you!

```
addRect.on('mouseover',function(d){
var tables = divContainer.selectAll('table').data(dataArray).enter().append('table')

var tablesHeader = tables.append('tr')
tablesHeader.append('th').attr('class','headerCell').attr('colspan', 2).append('td').html("Ranking / Name")
// tablesHeader.append('th').attr('class','rankingCell').append('td').html("Ranking")
// tablesHeader.append('th').attr('class','nameCell').append('td').html('Name')

// tables.selectAll(".tableRows").data(function(d){console.log(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum())}).enter()

var tableRows = tables.selectAll(".tableRows").data(function(d){ return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()}).enter()
.append('tr').attr('class','tableRows')
tableRows.append('td').attr('class','rankingCell').html(function(d) {return d.RANKING})
tableRows.append('td').attr('class','nameCell').html(function(d) {return d.PLAYER_NAME})

  })
  .on('mouseout',function(d){
      d3.select('.divContainer').style('display','none')
      d3.select('.divContainer').select('.upperArrow').remove()
      // d3.select('body').select('.divContainer').remove()
      d3.selectAll('table').selectAll('tr').data([]).exit().remove()
        d3.select('.divContainer').selectAll('table').data([]).exit().remove()
  })
```

Comment: This is a tip: create an *editable* version of your code, using [blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/) for instance. That way, people can actually try some solutions. Otherwise, people will have all the trouble of creating an editable, running code, *before* trying anything. And that trouble should be yours, don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

In your `mouseout` handler, instead of immediately removing the popup, wrap it in a `setTimeout` call (you could even use a d3 transition if you want it to fade or something). Then set up a `mouseover` handler for the popup and cancel the `setTimeout` until the user does a `mouseout` on the popup.